# Can we push custom logs of azure resources into in-built tables of Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to push custom logs into Log Analytics Workspace(LAW) using Data Collector API.
It is pushing the logs into Custom tables.

Can we push these logs into in-built tables(like AzureDiagnostics table) instead of custom tables ? Is it achievable .. if so, how can we do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api#record-type-and-properties)

> You define a custom record type when you submit data through the Azure Monitor HTTP Data Collector API. Currently, you can't write data to existing record types that were created by other data types and solutions. Azure Monitor reads the incoming data and then creates properties that match the data types of the values that you enter.

You can however write a kusto query that combines data from both your custom tables and built-in tables.